# Batch Script: move folders and retain 2 latest folders

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I'm new to scripting and I would like to ask something about moving files.
I have d:\tool directory and I want to move folders from that directory to the other network drive.
I also want to retain the latest 2 folders and just move the others.

Below script works in moving ang retaining files but only subdirectory are being copied.
For example in d:\tool, I have folders A, B, C.

folder A contains folder a1 (created date: 4/5/2013)..
folder B contains folder b2 (created date: 4/6/2013)..
folder C contains folder c3 (created date: 4/7/2013)..

But when I run my bat file, a1 folder was just transferred. I want it to be A with a1 in it. (Folders B and C get's retained)

```
net use m: /delete    
net use m: "\\test\mytools" test123 /USER:corp\testuser    
for /f "skip=2 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b  D:\tool') do robocopy  "%%F" "M:" /move /e    
net use m: /delete
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to exclude two named folders, or the oldest two with any name?

Answer (score 0):

Using this dir command in your for loop:

```
dir /ad /od /b
```

It includes only directories
It sorts the list by date so oldest folders are first

Then this code will extract the two top folders and they can be used as exclusions in the robocopy command:

```
net use m: /delete    
net use m: "\\test\mytools" test123 /USER:corp\testuser
set "a1="
set "a2="
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /ad /od /b "D:\tool"') do (
    if defined a1 if not defined a2 set "a2=%%F"
    if not defined a1 set "a1=%%F"
)
robocopy  "D:\tool" "M:\" /move /e /xd "%a1%" /xd "%a2%"
net use m: /delete
```

Make sure you have a backup of your tools folder - and test this with dummy files and folders.